# Im on a csv file using pandas and i have this error what do i do?

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, read.csv, pandas-datareader

im on a csv file and im using pandas i dont know what wrong with my code

```
df.describe([maximum]['Price(USD)'])
<>:1: SyntaxWarning: list indices must be integers or slices, not str; perhaps you missed a comma?
<>:1: SyntaxWarning: list indices must be integers or slices, not str; perhaps you missed a comma?
<ipython-input-70-6f9ec0183b49>:1: SyntaxWarning: list indices must be integers or slices, not str; perhaps you missed a comma?
  df.describe([maximum]['Price(USD)'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-6f9ec0183b49> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df.describe([maximum]['Price(USD)'])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: If the variable holding the dataframe is `maximum`, the syntax is `maximum['Price(USD)']`. You don't put the variable inside `[]`.

Comment: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable thats the error i get

Comment: That means that `maximum` is a function, not a dataframe. If the function returns a df, use `maximum()['Price(USD)']`. This is all just guesswork since you haven't provided a [mre].